# How do I program multiple user inputs for a JUnit unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I've been trying to unit test a specific method that, as part of the process, takes in two user inputs to first find the objects that match with the user input, then a second input to select from the list of matching results. However, when I try to write the unit test for it, the method will throw a NoSuchElementException in the test, citing that the 2nd instance of scanner.nextLine() is not detecting any element.

The unit test I've written is:

```
@Test
    public void testMultipleValidMenuInput(){
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("TestString\n1".getBytes());
        System.setIn(inputStream);
        sampleAccount.enrolCourse(sampleList);
        Assert.assertEquals("FirstExpectedLine\nSecondExpectedLine", outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim());
    }
```

and the full method is:

```
public void enrolCourse(courseList listOfCourses){
        ArrayList<Course> applicableCourses = new ArrayList<Course>();
        Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchTerm = scanVar.nextLine();
        boolean termFound = false;
        for (Course e: listOfCourses.getCourseList()) {
            if (e.getCourseName().toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
                applicableCourses.add(e);
                System.out.println(e.getCourseName() + " has been found.");
                termFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (!termFound) {
            System.out.printf("Courses containing %s has not been found. %n", searchTerm);
        } else if (applicableCourses.size() == 1) {
            if (enrolmentList.contains(applicableCourses.get(0))) {
                System.out.println("Course already enrolled in account.");
            } else {
                enrolmentList.add(applicableCourses.get(0));
                System.out.printf("%s has been added to your enrolment.%n", applicableCourses.get(0).getCourseName());
            }
        } else if (applicableCourses.size() > 1) {
            boolean selectionNotMade = true;
            do {
                try{
                    selectionNotMade = menuSelect(applicableCourses, true);
                } catch (DuplicateClassException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
                }
            while(selectionNotMade);
            }
        }
private boolean menuSelect(ArrayList<Course> courseArray, boolean enrolOrWithdraw) throws DuplicateClassException{
        Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < courseArray.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s ) %s %n", i+1, courseArray.get(i).getCourseName());
        }
        System.out.println("Please select a number according to which course you would like.");
        try {
            int inputVar = Character.getNumericValue(scanVar.nextLine().charAt(0));
            if (enrolOrWithdraw) {
                if (!enrolmentList.contains(courseArray.get(inputVar-1))) {
                    enrolmentList.add(courseArray.get(inputVar-1));
                }
                else {
                    throw new DuplicateClassException("Course already enrolled in account.");
                }
                return false;
            }
            else {
                enrolmentList.remove(courseArray.get(inputVar-1));
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("Selection could not be made.");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

where the exception is being thrown in the menuSelect method portion:
`int inputVar = Character.getNumericValue(scanVar.nextLine().charAt(0));`
Everything I've googled so far says I only need to use \n in the inputStream to separate inputs, but its clearly not working.

Comment: Much better to pass the Scanner into the method you're testing, and then mock the Scanner in the test, instead of creating the Scanner in the method.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? I'm not quite sure what you mean by passing the scanner into enrolCourse()

Answer (score 0):

On linux machines \n is enough to mark end of line, but I think on windows machine you should use \r\n for end of line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public void enrolCourse(courseList listOfCourses, Scanner scanvar){
...
}
```

and run your test with:

```
public void testMultipleValidMenuInput(){
  Scanner scanner = Mockito.mock(Scanner.class);
  Mockito.when(scanner.nextLine()).thenReturn("TestString").thenReturn("1");
  ... // further mocking

  sampleAccount.enrolCourse(sampleList, scanner);
        Assert.assertEquals("FirstExpectedLine\nSecondExpectedLine", outputStreamCaptor.toString().trim());
    }
```

You can take the same approach with `System.out` -- passing an `OutputStream` to your function which you mock during your tests.

I suggest you work through some Mockito tutorials.

Comment: Could you just elaborate on how to add a 2nd testString in the section where its further mocking? I've never heard of Mockito, so a further clarification on how to allow for multiple inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added another `thenReturn` call for the second input string.